# How to fix this Bootstrap Compatibility issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to follow an example of an image puzzle it works well but once twitter bootstrap is referenced the grids no longer work well. I have listed the markup and js below.

The HTML is as below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Image Puzzle</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--removing the bootstrap reference above makes it work-->

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/image-puzzle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/image-puzzle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="collage">
        <h2>Image Puzzle</h2>
        <h3>TIME LEFT: <span id="timeLeft"></span></h3>
        <hr />
        <div id="playPanel" style="padding:5px!important;display:none!important;">
            <h3 id="imgTitle"></h3> <hr />
            <div style="display:inline-block!important; margin:auto!important; width:95%!important; vertical-align:top!important;">
                <ul id="sortable" class="sortable"></ul>
                <div id="actualImageBox">
                    <div id="stepBox">
                        <div>Steps:</div><div class="stepCount">0</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="timeBox">
                        Time Taken: <span id="timerPanel"></span> secs
                    </div>
                    <img id="actualImage" />
                    <div>Re-arrange to create a picture like this.</div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gameOver" style="display:none;">
            <div style="background-color:mediumspringgreen; padding: 5px 10px 20px 10px; text-align: center; ">
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Game Over!!</h2>
                <p>Congratulations!!  You won by <span class="stepCount">0</span> steps. </p>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div>
                    <label>Select Network Provider:</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="AIRTEL">AIRTEL</option>
                        <option value="ETISALAT">ETISALAT</option>
                        <option value="GLO">GLO</option>
                        <option value="MTN">MTN</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" maxlength="11" />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Play Again</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gameLost" style="display:none;">
            <div style="background-color: Red; padding: 5px 10px 20px 10px; text-align: center; ">
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Game Over!!</h2>
                Sorry <br /> You Could not finish the game in the given time.
                <br />
                Steps: <span class="stepCount">0</span> steps.
                <br />
               <div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Play Again</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var images = [

                { src: 'images/Ada.jpg', title: 'Ada' },
                { src: 'images/Me2.jpg', title: 'Me 2' },
                { src: 'images/Me1.jpg', title: 'Me' }
            ];

            $(function () {
                var gridSize = $('#levelPanel :radio:checked').val();
                imagePuzzle.startGame(images, 3);
                $('#newPhoto').click(function () {
                    imagePuzzle.startGame(images, gridSize);
                });

                $('#levelPanel :radio').change(function (e) {
                    var gridSize = $(this).val();
                    imagePuzzle.startGame(images, gridSize);
                });
            });
      </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript is as below,

```
    <code>
    var timerFunction;
    var millisecondsallowed = 30000;


    var imagePuzzle = {
        stepCount: 0,
        startTime: new Date().getTime(),
        startGame: function (images, gridSize) {
            console.log(gridSize);
            this.setImage(images, gridSize);
            $('#playPanel').show();
            $('#sortable').randomize();
            this.enableSwapping('#sortable li');
            this.stepCount = 0;
            this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
            this.tick();
        },
        tick: function () {

            if (millisecondsallowed == 0) {
                clearTimeout(timerFunction);
                $('#actualImageBox').empty().html($('#gameLost').html());
                $('#sortable').empty();

                return;
            }

            var timeLeft = parseInt((millisecondsallowed - 1000));
            millisecondsallowed = millisecondsallowed - 1000;
            $('#timeLeft').text(parseInt(timeLeft / 1000));
            timerFunction = setTimeout(imagePuzzle.tick, 1000);
        },
        enableSwapping: function (elem) {
            $(elem).draggable({
                snap: '#droppable',
                snapMode: 'outer',
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: "clone"
            });
            $(elem).droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var $dragElem = $(ui.draggable).clone().replaceAll(this);
                    $(this).replaceAll(ui.draggable);

                    currentList = $('#sortable > li').map(function (i, el) { return $(el).attr('data-value'); });
                    if (isSorted(currentList)) {
                        $('#actualImageBox').empty().html($('#gameOver').html());
                        $('#sortable').empty();

                        clearTimeout(timerFunction);
                    } else {
                        var now = new Date().getTime();
                        imagePuzzle.stepCount++;
                        $('.stepCount').text(imagePuzzle.stepCount);
                        //$('.timeCount').text(parseInt((now - imagePuzzle.startTime) / 1000, 10));
                    }

                    imagePuzzle.enableSwapping(this);
                    imagePuzzle.enableSwapping($dragElem);
                }
            });
        },

        setImage: function (images, gridSize) {
            console.log(gridSize);
            gridSize = gridSize || 4; // If gridSize is null or not passed, default it as 4.
            console.log(gridSize);
            var percentage = 100 / (gridSize - 1);
            var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
            $('#imgTitle').html(image.title);
            $('#actualImage').attr('src', image.src);
            $('#sortable').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
                var xpos = (percentage * (i % gridSize)) + '%';
                var ypos = (percentage * Math.floor(i / gridSize)) + '%';
                var li = $('<li class="item" data-value="' + (i) + '"></li>').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + image.src + ')',
                    'background-size': (gridSize * 100) + '%',
                    'background-position': xpos + ' ' + ypos,
                    'width': 400 / gridSize,
                    'height': 400 / gridSize
                });
                $('#sortable').append(li);
            }
            $('#sortable').randomize();
        }
    };

    function isSorted(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != i)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $.fn.randomize = function (selector) {
        var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
            $parents = $elems.parent();

        $parents.each(function () {
            $(this).children(selector).sort(function () {
                return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
            }).remove().appendTo(this);
        });
        return this;
    };
    </code>
```

Comment: Please post your markup so we can try and see what might be going wrong. Kinda hard to tell you what's wrong if we can't see your code to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I have Added the script and markup. Thanks

Comment: @MattD Added the codes

Comment: If having the bootstrap refference causes it to break, try introducing it at a later point in the document header, or figure out what items in Bootstrap are causing the issue and then customize your Bootstrap implementation to not include those elements, if they can be avoided. Otherwise you'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this line to the image-puzzle.css

```
#playPanel * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```